# C++ reading a txt file with pixel's colors and copy them in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, colors

My problem is that I have a text file with inside the color of each pixel of a png of the graph of an oscilloscope with two curves.

For example 0 is for white pixel, that is background color, and then 247 for one of the four reference pixel and then the colors of the pixels of the 2 curves.

What my program should do it's open the file read and save: the width, height, number of colors, and the number associated to each color. 
Then save all the pixels in an array so that I can read each element of the array searching for the pixels of reference and of the 2 curves and save their coordination in another file.

I wrote down my code but I'm not sure that it actually saves the pixels in the array, because if I ask the program to give me an element of the array it gives me nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream f_in;
    f_in.open("Pixmap1.txt");
    if (f_in.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error during the opening of the file";
    }
    int width(0);
    int height(0);
    int numbercolors;
    int referencepixel1;
    int referencepixel2;
    int referencepixel3;
    int referencepixel4;
    int C1;
    int C2;

    f_in>>width;
        if(f_in.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error during the reading of width";
    }
    f_in>>height;
        if(f_in.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error during the reading of height";
    }
    f_in>>numbercolors;
        if(f_in.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error during the reading of numberofcolors";
    }
    f_in>>referencepixel1;
        if(f_in.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error during the reading of referencepixel1 ";
    }
    f_in>>referencepixel2;
        if(f_in.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error during the reading of nreferencepixel2";
    }
    f_in>>referencepixel3;
        if(f_in.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error during the reading of referencepixel3";
    }
    f_in>>referencepixel4;
        if(f_in.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error during the reading of referencepixel4";
    }
    f_in>>C1;
        if(f_in.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error during the reading of C1";
    }
    f_in>>C2;
        if(f_in.fail()){
        cerr<<"Error during the reading of C2";
    }
    vector<vector<int> > MyArrayPix;
    int i(0);
    while(i<height,i++){
        vector<int> Vtmp;
        int j(0);
        while(j<width,j++){
            int tmp(0);
            f_in>>tmp;
            Vtmp.push_back(tmp);
        }
        MyArrayPix.push_back(Vtmp);
    }
    f_in.close();
    ofstream f_out;
    f_out.open("traces.m");
    string stmp("P = [");
    f_out<<stmp;
    int Y(0);
    int X(0);
    while(Y<height,Y++){
        while(X<width,X++){
            if(MyArrayPix[Y][X]=referencepixel1){
                f_out<<Y<<X<<endl;              
            }
            if(MyArrayPix[Y][X]=referencepixel2){
                f_out<<Y<<X<<endl;              
            }
            if(MyArrayPix[Y][X]=referencepixel3){
                f_out<<Y<<X<<endl;              
            }
            if(MyArrayPix[Y][X]=referencepixel4){
                f_out<<Y<<X<<endl;              
            }
        }
    }
    string stmp1("] ;");
    f_out<<stmp1<<endl;
    string stmp2("C1 = [");
    f_out<<stmp2;
        while(Y<height,Y++){
            while(X<width,X++){
                if(MyArrayPix[Y][X]=C1){
                    f_out<<Y<<X<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
    string stmp3("] ;");
    f_out<<stmp3<<endl;
    string stmp4("C2 = [");
    f_out<<stmp4;
    while(Y<height,Y++){
            while(X<width,X++){
                if(MyArrayPix[Y][X]=C2){
                    f_out<<Y<<X<<endl;
                }
            }
    }
    string stmp5("] ;");
    f_out<<stmp5<<endl;
    f_out.close();
}
```

Comment: `if (!(f_in >> xyz)) cerr << "some error message";` (also you probably want to abord if any of those fail?)

Comment: Could you show us an example of input please?

Comment: What are the ranges for the pixels?  Are the pixels 8-bit, 16-bit, 24-bit?

Comment: You are using `int` for the height and width. The `int` can be negative.  Can your height and width be negative?  There is an `unsigned` integer.

Comment: You may want to use `unsigned` for the pixels.  The *signed* int requires one bit for the sign value, leaving you with one less bit.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  The debugger allows you to execute one statement at a time and *watch* the values in variables.  A lot faster than posting to StackOverflow and *waiting* for somebody to either use a debugger on your code or inspect your code.

Comment: @Aflerdo `while(Y<height,Y++)` (and a lot of similar statements) do probably not what you think. It checks `Y<height` discards the boolean result, checks `Y` (in `Y++`) for not 0 and performs the increment afterwards. (This is how the `,` operator works.) `for (int Y = 0; Y < height; ++Y)` would do as well as `int Y(0); for (; Y < height; ++Y)` and even `int Y(0); for (; Y < height; Y++)` although there is no advantage for the post-fix increment instead of a pre-fix increment in the latter case.

Comment: Thank you very much @Scheff

Comment: I changed the while with the for and now it works